# PHP scripts on WAMP generating errors

Tags: php, zend-framework, wampserver

I'm getting below errors from my local WAMP environment

```
Unknown error: Non-static method SJB_System::shutdownFunction() should not be called statically in C:\wamp\www\engjobs\system\core\System.php on line 161
Unknown error: Declaration of GoogleSocialPlugin::ifUserIsRegistered() should be compatible with SJB_SocialPlugin::ifUserIsRegistered($network, $profileSocialID = NULL) in C:\wamp\www\engjobs\system\plugins\google_integration_plugin\google_integration_plugin.php on line 9
Unknown error: Non-static method GoogleSocialPlugin::getNetwork() should not be called statically in C:\wamp\www\engjobs\system\plugins\google_integration_plugin\index.php on line 7
Unknown error: Non-static method SJB_SocialPlugin::getNetwork() should not be called statically in C:\wamp\www\engjobs\system\plugins\google_integration_plugin\index.php on line 7
Unknown error: Declaration of SJB_TwitterDetails::getDetails() should be compatible with SJB_ObjectDetails::getDetails() in C:\wamp\www\engjobs\system\plugins\twitter_integration_plugin\Twitter\TwitterDetails.php on line 156
```

I wasn't getting this from production server but with WAMP I'm getting this.

It's PHP, custom framework called Smart Job Board which is built on top of Zend framework

Comment: WAMP probably has a different PHP error reporting level to your production web server - [read this for help](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

Comment: Are your PHP versions the same? Do you have error reporting set to the same values on each server?

Comment: WAMP has Xdebug on and production doesn't

Comment: Production is PHP 5.3.15 and Development is 5.4.3

Comment: All files and database are copied across. Just the config were changed like database credentials and site_url